# Get working dir from wordpress.com site

Tags: wordpress

I'm not a WordPress expert here but I got a account and a preminum version with a template but I want to download the entire directory so I can modify php files, styles etc.

How do I do this and also how do I upload it to the wordpress site itself since it's live.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that on wordpress.com site.

But you can edit some files from within your wordpress admin panel editor.

Comment: @user2945872 ok, does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah I have to look into the admin panel editor then